# Match Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this issue with patterns in C#.

I have this pattern:

```
1111100000000000000000000
```

It is a `row` of 25 1 or 0's.

This `pattern` should match every string that has the same 1's on the same place, but it should ignore if the `string` has 1 on the place that the `pattern` has 0.
The only thing the `pattern` should check is if the 1's is one the right place.

ex.

The pattern should match:

```
1111100000000000000000000

1111100000001000100010001

1111111110000111100111100
```

But not:

```
0111110000101110001011000

1011111010101010101000000
```

I have tried this, with regular expressions:

```
       var orginal_pattern = "1111100000000000000000000";
       var match_pattern =   "1111100000000000010000000";

       var pattern = orginal_pattern.Replace("0", "[?]");
       Debug.WriteLine(pattern);

       var RegMatch = Regex.Match(match_pattern, pattern);

       Debug.WriteLine(RegMatch.Success);
```

I hope someone could give me an idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find many talented software engineers here who are eager to _help_ you. When you ask to have your program written for you, however, you'll receive little sympathy. Please show what you've accomplished so far and what _specific_ roadblock you're encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your strings to int and use `AND` operator

```
int pattern = Convert.ToInt32("1111100000000000000000000", 2);
int[] nums = new int[]{
    Convert.ToInt32("1111100000000000000000000", 2),
    Convert.ToInt32("1111100000001000100010001", 2),
    Convert.ToInt32("1111111110000111100111100", 2),
    Convert.ToInt32("0111110000101110001011000", 2),
    Convert.ToInt32("1011111010101010101000000", 2),
};

foreach (var num in nums)
{
    bool b = (pattern & num)==pattern;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
True
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned something new today :D